# Installing Gazebo 5.0 along with with Gazebo 2.2 and ROS Indigo (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I have ROS Indigo installed with Gazebo 2.2 which comes by default with it. I also want to install Gazebo 5.0 as I want to use its Import feature to import a building floor plan (Building editor) which comes in Gazebo 5.0, I dont have to use Gazebo 5.0 with ROS indigo.
When I try the answer here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7999/gazebo5-ros-packages/ it tells me that it will remove ROS Indigo from the machine which I dont want obviously. Is there any way of installing Gazebo 5.0 along with ROS Indigo and Gazebo 2.2?

Thanks in advance.
Naman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8187/installing-gazebo-5.0-along-with-with-gazebo-2.2-and-ros-indigo-(ubuntu-14.04)/) by [Naman91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1129/naman91/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Maybe this [answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8159/want-to-install-gazebo5-but-has-ros-indigo/) helps you. Or you can install Gazebo5.0 from source and remember to source the correct version of setup.bash when you use gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2015-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Follow the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros) and you can install `ros-indigo-gazebo5-ros-pkgs`.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman91](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1129/naman91/) on 2015-03-09**:
Thanks for the reply. I tried it couple of days back. While installing it tells that it will remove some packages including ros-indigo-desktop-full which I obviously dont want. Is it because of some compatibility issues between Gazebo 5.0 and ROS Indigo? Is there any way around it?

**Comment by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on 2015-03-11**:
It will actually remove gazebo 2 which comes  along with ROS Indigo. I have already removed gazebo 2.0 in indigo and install gazebo 5.0 and also install ros-indigo-gazebo5-ros-pkgs. It works pretty well.

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-04-25**:
This doesn't work. I have this package, and `rosdep install` still throws and error.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-04-27**:
I think `rosdep install` won't work when the `ros-indigo-gazebo5-ros-pkgs` debian is installed.